Water heater replacement
I've owned my house for over a year. My Rheems water heater was installed in 2004 and is now 20 years old. Just today, I noticed some water at the base of the heater. On further inspection, I found that leak originated in the cold water supply connection and anode rod.  I've since shut off gas and water supply and spoken to my plumber. He suggested replacing the water heater, especially based on the age. My questions are:

Is a replacement necessary or can this be fixed by just tightening the pipes, and some routine maintenance?
My heater, along with HVAC rests on a raised wooden platform in my garage. The water has been pooling on this wood undetected presumably for a while. I am afraid that the moisture and low ventilation may have weakened the wood. What can I do to repair it and make sure it can bear the weight of the water heater?




It is twice s old as normal

@Traveler ???? That is a meaningless statement. If you mean "twice as old as normal end-of-life", say so. If you mean "twice the average age of a water heater in the US", say so. If it is something else, say so.

Your heater has had a good run, and given you (well, the PO) more service than you could've expected.  Retire it.

Replace. Schedule "inspect the anode rod" for 2029 on the new heater, and replace  if needed then. Schedule the next inspection or replacement depending on what you find then. Flush annually. Flushing is easy, anode rod inpections/replacements usually are not. They really hope you'll ignore the anode rod and let the heater rust out, rather than inspect and replace it when needed, so they make it a pain to get out, normally.

If the platform was constructed with a clue, it would be water-resistant wood. In any case, it's either not rotten and does not need replacement, or rotten and does. If the latter, use marine plywood and pressure treated framing lumber and it won't be an issue the next time.

Should I buy Rheem or Bratford White?

@YashS  That is a shopping/product recommendation, which is not allowed on here.  Read reviews on third party(not stores/company) sites.

Consider a heat-pump water heater. https://youtu.be/zheQKmAT_a0?si=ZRerJEU6qFah2A2H&t=295

With unknown maintenance done to it before, plus leaking, repair might work for a short time or make it worst.
At 20 years old, replacement is usually the best choice, since it removes the repair cost from replacement cost.
The wood is replaced if needed.
